# Creating loop from another loop values using dividing

Tags: python-2.7

```
import math

def s(x):
return 0.298**k/math.factorial(k)

for k in range(0,5):
print (s(k))
```

Hi, I'm new to python, I hope someone can help me with this loop.

So, I wanted to make a loop using function s(x) and numbers from 1 to 5. The code above does that and gives me values:

```
A1 - 1.0
A2 - 0.298
A3 - 0.044402
A4 - 0.00441059866667
A5 - 0.000328589600667
```

but now I also need to create a second list like this:

```
R1. value = 0.298/0
R2. value = 0.444402/0.298
R3. value = 0.00441059866667/0.444402
```

and so on..

Basically, the formula for this is R1=A1/A0, R2=A2/A1, R3=A3/A2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math

def s(x):
    return 0.298**k/math.factorial(k)

prevSK = 0
for k in range(0,5):
    try:
        print (s(k))
        print (s(k)/prevSK)
        prevSK = s(k)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        prevSK = s(k)

        continue
```